# Query for making multiple indefinite rows into one row with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

| ID | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |

And the second one

| ID2 | Code | Date1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01/01/2023 |
| 2 | B | 01/02/2023 |
| 3 | C | 01/03/2023 |
| 4 | A | 01/01/2023 |
| 5 | D | 01/15/2023 |

The second table has more columns that I need to include, but I'm only including two (Code and Date1) for the sake of brevity.

What I need is to unite everything based on the ID of the first table. So it would look something like

| ID1 | ID2-1 | Code-1 | Date1-1 | ID2-2 | Code-2 | Date1-2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 01/01/2023 | 2 | B | 01/02/2023 |
| 2 | 3 | C | 01/03/2023 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 4 | A | 01/01/2023 | 5 | D | 01/15/2023 |

In these examples one ID repeats up to two times in the second table, but the second table can have an indefinite amount of records tied to an ID from the first table. Meaning it might be Code-10, or Code-20, or maybe more or less. I need to do this in a pretty big query for a report I'm doing, so these are not the only fields that will be in the final result, but for this data specifically I only use two tables that have a very similar structure to the one I'm describing here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your "Code-10" example imply you will want one row triplet of ID-Code-Date (and more) for each of the 10 codes? That's a lot of columns.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis no attempt maybe? Wasn't me though.

Comment: isn't it better to do this kind of pivoting in the report itself, even Crystal reports have built-in pivot support. I don't think SQL Server does dynamic pivoting easy, and if you don't know the number of columns, how are you gonna code your report code to display them

Comment: @siggemannen is correct. Most reporting software, and even Excel, can pivot far better than SQL Server can do it, when you don't know how many columns you'll have. The only way to do it in pure SQL Server is with dynamic SQL, which is not easy to work with.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Yeah I was actually thinking the same thing, that I should probably use Excel itself to do this. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on T N's code, this puppy builds a "dynamic" 30 column wide pivot.

```sql
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = N'
SELECT
    A.ID
    [COLUMNS]
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID2) AS RowNum
    FROM TableA
) A
JOIN TableB B
    ON B.ID2 = A.ID2
GROUP BY A.ID
ORDER BY A.ID'

SELECT  @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '[COLUMNS]', (
        SELECT  CONCAT(N'
        ,   MAX(CASE WHEN A.RowNum = ',  x.sort, ' THEN B.ID2 END) AS [ID2-', x.sort, N']
        ,   MAX(CASE WHEN A.RowNum = ', x.sort, ' THEN B.Code END) AS [Code-', x.sort, N']
        ,   MAX(CASE WHEN A.RowNum = ', x.sort, ' THEN B.Date END) AS [Date-', x.sort, N']')
        FROM    (
            SELECT  TOP 30 row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT   NULL)) AS sort
            FROM    sys.objects so
            ) x
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))
SELECT  @SQL


EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Nice. Of course I had to try the above in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZEAqe190). Only got 8 groups at first. Then realized that was all that the `sys.objects` table could serve up in the base fiddle environment. Reran using the 2022 `GENERATE_SERIES()` function and got good results. Cross joining two sys.object tables also works.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using a combination of a windowed `ROW_NUMBER()` number function and *conditional aggregation*.

First, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)` is used to assign sequences number to each row with the same ID. The results are then be joined with your second table and a `GROUP BY ID` is applied. Finally, conditional aggregation functions of the form `MAX(CASE WHEN ... THEN .. END)` can be used to select the proper value for each column, with specific row numbers assigned to specific columns.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    A.ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN A.RowNum = 1 THEN B.ID2 END) AS [ID2-1],
    MAX(CASE WHEN A.RowNum = 1 THEN B.Code END) AS [Code-1],
    MAX(CASE WHEN A.RowNum = 1 THEN B.Date END) AS [Date-1],
    MAX(CASE WHEN A.RowNum = 2 THEN B.ID2 END) AS [ID2-2],
    MAX(CASE WHEN A.RowNum = 2 THEN B.Code END) AS [Code-2],
    MAX(CASE WHEN A.RowNum = 2 THEN B.Date END) AS [Date-2]
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID2) AS RowNum
    FROM TableA
) A
JOIN TableB B
    ON B.ID2 = A.ID2
GROUP BY A.ID
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Results:

| ID | ID2-1 | Code-1 | Date-1 | ID2-2 | Code-2 | Date-2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 2023-01-01 | 2 | B | 2023-01-02 |
| 2 | 3 | C | 2023-01-03 | null | null | null |
| 3 | 4 | A | 2023-01-01 | 5 | D | 2023-01-15 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hwqFBx6g).

If you need to support an arbitrary number of records per ID instead of just two, you will then need to dive into the world of dynamic SQL.